# NullPointerException in getView method for ApkAdapter class which extends BaseAdapter

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments, nullpointerexception

I am trying to get a ListView of user installed android apps to show up in a fragment in my android app. I am populating its items using custom BaseAdapter.

Since I am using a fragment, I am running into problems.

I had to convert my Activity to Fragment. I did that successfully, but after that I got runtime errors in my Adapter class.

```
06-23 00:40:53.824  23082-23082/com.spicycurryman.getdisciplined10.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.ibc.android.demo.appslist.app.ApkAdapter.getView(ApkAdapter.java:50)
```

LayoutInflator is line 50 where is error is

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) convertView.getContext().getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
```

I did some research

[NullPointerException in getView Of Adapter extends BaseAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18102388/nullpointerexception-in-getview-of-adapter-extends-baseadapter)

[extends BaseAdapter appear NullPointerException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7410701/extends-baseadapter-appear-nullpointerexception)

and attempted to follow these; however, the solution still produced the error.

I am not sure why `convertView == null` is always false.

```
package com.ibc.android.demo.appslist.app;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.spicycurryman.getdisciplined10.app.InstalledAppActivity;
import com.spicycurryman.getdisciplined10.app.R;

import java.util.List;

public class ApkAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    List<PackageInfo> packageList;
    InstalledAppActivity context;
    PackageManager packageManager;

    public ApkAdapter(InstalledAppActivity context, List<PackageInfo> packageList,
                      PackageManager packageManager) {
        super();
        this.context = context;
        this.packageList = packageList;
        this.packageManager = packageManager;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView apkName;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return packageList.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return packageList.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        // LayoutInflator is line 50 where is error is
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) convertView.getContext().getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.installed_apps, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.apkName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.appname);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        PackageInfo packageInfo = (PackageInfo) getItem(position);
        Drawable appIcon = packageManager
                .getApplicationIcon(packageInfo.applicationInfo);
        String appName = packageManager.getApplicationLabel(
                packageInfo.applicationInfo).toString();
        appIcon.setBounds(0, 0, 65, 65);
        holder.apkName.setCompoundDrawables(appIcon, null, null, null);
        holder.apkName.setCompoundDrawablePadding(15);
        holder.apkName.setText(appName);

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Here is my Fragment class:

```
package com.spicycurryman.getdisciplined10.app;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.ibc.android.demo.appslist.app.ApkAdapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;



public class InstalledAppActivity extends Fragment
        implements OnItemClickListener {

    PackageManager packageManager;
    ListView apkList;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.installed_apps, container, false);
        packageManager = getActivity().getPackageManager();
        List<PackageInfo> packageList = packageManager
                .getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);

        List<PackageInfo> packageList1 = new ArrayList<PackageInfo>();

        /*To filter out System apps*/
        for(PackageInfo pi : packageList) {
            boolean b = isSystemPackage(pi);
            if(!b) {
                packageList1.add(pi);
            }
        }
        apkList = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.applist);
        apkList.setAdapter(new ApkAdapter(this, packageList1, packageManager));

        apkList.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        return rootView;

    }

    /**
     * Return whether the given PackgeInfo represents a system package or not.
     * User-installed packages (Market or otherwise) should not be denoted as
     * system packages.
     *
     * @param pkgInfo
     * @return boolean
     */
    private boolean isSystemPackage(PackageInfo pkgInfo) {
        return ((pkgInfo.applicationInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) != 0) ? true
                : false;
    }


// Don't need in Fragment
 /*   @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.block, menu);
        return true;
    }*/

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

    }
}
```

Please remember that InstalledAppActivity is a **fragment**.

***EDIT:***

Here are my updated errors

[image]

[image]

Comment: what is at `ApkAdapter.java:50` ??

Comment: Let me comment that and make it explicit my mistake

Comment: @XiJiaopin could you indicate line 50??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this

```
  apkList.setAdapter(new ApkAdapter(this, packageList1, packageManager));
```

to

```
 apkList.setAdapter(new ApkAdapter(getActivity(), packageList1, packageManager));
```

`this` in Fragment does not refer to valid context.

Also

```
LayoutInflater inflater; // declare as instance variable
```

Then in the constructor

```
public ApkAdapter(Context context, List<PackageInfo> packageList,
                  PackageManager packageManager) {
    super();
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context); // can initialize here
```

Comment: apkList.setAdapter(new ApkAdapter(getActivity(), packageList1, packageManager));
 cannot be applied

Comment: @XiJiaopin what cannot be applied??

Comment: context layoutinflater cannot be applied

Comment: And I still get an error in  apkList.setAdapter(new ApkAdapter(getActivity(), packageList1, packageManager));

Comment: @XiJiaopin its a typo its `LayoutInflater`.

Comment: @XiJiaopin a similar example. complete one @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18162931/get-selected-item-using-checkbox-in-listview

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56091/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-xijiaopin).

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to obtain the `context` from a `view` that is `null`, this is why the app crashes. Modifying the below line in the `getView()` function will solve the issue

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
```